# How do HashMap.values() and HashMap.keySet() return values and keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

The source code of `HashMap.values()` is shown as follows

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<V> vs = values;
    return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
}
```

As you can see, when the `values()` method first called, it just returns a `Values` object. The `Values` object is a subclass of `AbstractCollection` with no constructor, and of course contains no element. But when I called the method, it returned a collection rapidly

```
Collection<String> values = map.values();
System.out.println(values);
```

That's so weird. Not only `values()`, but also `keySet()` and `entrySet()` method return such empty objects. So, here is my question, when and how do these methods return objects with elements we need?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a misconception that the `Values` class is "of course empty". Just because there is no method called on it and its constructor doesn't have any arguments doesn't mean that the collection is empty.

The `Values` class is an "inner class" (a non-static [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)) of `HashMap`, which means that it has an implicit reference to the `HashMap` object that created it. It can therefore access all elements of the `HashMap`, either explicitly by using the `HashMap.this` reference or by just accessing the members directly. Since it is an inner class, it is even allowed to access the `HashMap`'s private members.

You can see that for example in the `Values` class' implementation of the `size` method:

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

The `Values` class doesn't have a `size` member, so that `size` refers to the `HashMap`'s size. It's equivalent to:

```
public int size() {
    return HashMap.this.size;
}
```

**EDIT:** Note that this also means that the collection you receive is not a copy, but still refers to the original `HashMap` contents and therefore changes when you update the `HashMap`:

```
    // Getting the entry set (not a copy!)
    Set<Entry<String, String>> entries = map.entrySet();

    // Add elements to the map afterwards
    map.put("abc", "def");

    // Check out the entries in the collection
    // (magically containing the elements added after getting the collection)
    System.out.println(entries); // "[abc=def]"
```

Comment: `Note that this also means that the collection you receive is not a copy, but still refers to the original HashMap contents and therefore changes when you update the HashMap:` Which is also clearly spelled out in the contract of `Map.values()`, to avoid any misunderstanding.

Comment: An inner class is a non-static nested class, i.e. had the class been static, it would not be an inner class, but simply a static nested class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @Sardtok: Thanks for the hint, I just edited the answer in order to use the official terminology.

Answer (score 13):

The `Values` class implements a `Collection` that is backed by the `HashMap`. As mastov commented, `Values` is an inner class of `HashMap`, which gives it access to the members of the enclosing `HashMap` instance it is associated with. Therefore it's not empty. Its size is the size of the `HashMap`, and when you iterate over it, you are iterating over the Entries of the `HashMap`.

When you call `System.out.println(values);`, you are calling the `toString` method of `AbstractCollection`, which uses an `Iterator` to iterate over the values and get their `String` representation. The `Iterator` actually iterates over the Entries of the `HashMap` and returns their values.

The same goes for the `Set`s returned by `keySet` and `entrySet`.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that the `Values` class is a non-static inner class that therefore has an implicit `this` pointer to the outer class `HashMap`. That's how it can reference the elements of the map, even when its constructor is called with no arguments at all.

Comment: Thanks @Eran and @mastov. I know the iterator method can work well when we iterate `Values`. However, when I set a breakpoint at the `Collection<String> values = map.values();` line and debug the program, the values has already been set as a collection before `System.out.println(values)` been called, and there is no iteration here. This is the point where I feel strange.

Comment: @Yohn What do you mean by `the values has already been set as a collection`?

Comment: I mean that when a breakpoint is set at the `Collection<String> values = map.values();` line in IDE like Eclipse, run the program as debug mode, and step over the line, the IDE will show that the variable `values` has been a collection filled with all values of Hashmap, rather than an object only with some references.

Comment: @Yohn I tried similar code in Eclipse, and when I watch the `values` variable I see it contains only `this$0`, which contains all the members of the `HashMap` (which is the enclosing instance of the Values instance). The Values class has no data members of its own. You are seeing the members of the `HashMap`.

Comment: @Eran Yes, the variable contains a `this$0` referenced to hashmap, but when move the mouse to hover over the `values` variable, or just click the `values` variable in the `Variables` view, you can see a small window with all values in the `values` variable.

Comment: @Yohn Clicking the values variable in the Variables view just executes the toString method of that Collection and shows it's output, so again, the Iterator is used to obtain the values from the HashMap.

Comment: OK, I got it, `Clicking variable in the Variables view just executes the toString method`, I should have thought of that, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
Collection<V> vs = values;
return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
```

These two line answer your question.

`values` is a internal collection (Inherited from `AbstractMap`). If it is not `null` then it will be returned.
If it is `null` then it will be initialized and the new one will returned.

Now I guess, the main point of your question is
**when and how do these methods return objects with elements we need?**

Technically `values`always  return this initialized Object. Then how we get our entry values from these object.?
Lets go a little deep:

values()  actually return an object of class `Values` which is an Inner class of `HashMap` and extends `AbstractCollection`

```
private final class Values extends AbstractCollection<V>
```

As you have looked into the source code. Then you will find inside the `Values` class

```
public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return newValueIterator();
    }
```

this `newValueIterator()` does  the trick.
If you go more deeper you will find  `newValueIterator()` returns object of `ValueIterator` which is a subclass of `HashIterator`
`HashIterator` implements basic functionality for iteration, which actually itterate over the `table` maintained by the `HashMap`.